# How can i get value?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I extract value from response?
Output of alert is [{"maturitydays":"120"}]
I only want value!!

```
$("#selectCrop").change(function(){   //this ajax will bring default configured crop data
    var cropid = $("#selectCrop option:selected").val();
    var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/cropConfig/getData";
    $.ajax({
        data    : {'cropid':cropid},
        type    : 'post',
        url     : url,
        success :function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: @MaximShoustin Actually it's an array, so: `response[0].maturitydays`

Comment: @ErenTantekin yes it should take 0 item first

Answer (score 2):

It appears your response is inside an array due to the square brackets, this means you need to get the value through:

```
response[0]['maturitydays']
```

So your code will look like:

```
$("#selectCrop").change(function(){   //this ajax will bring default configured crop data
                                var cropid = $("#selectCrop option:selected").val();
                                var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/cropConfig/getData";
                                    $.ajax({
                                    data    : {'cropid':cropid},
                                    type    : 'post',
                                    url     : url,
                                    success :function(response) {
                                        alert(response[0]['maturitydays']);
                                    }
                                    })
                                });
```

Comment: response[0]["maturitydays"] to be like this response[0]['maturitydays']                thanks for your help   It was helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's json.

Use json_decode to make it array then grab the value from the array (if you must).

```
$array = json_decode('{"maturitydays":"120"}',true);
$value=$array["maturitydays"];
Echo $value;
```

https://3v4l.org/Uc51m

Answer (score 0):

The data that you get as response is a `JSON array` with a number of `JSON objects`. JSON (JavaScript object notation) can be used as a JavaScript `object` right away (as long as its not in `string` form, in which case it has to be parsed with `JSON.parse`).
When you receive the response you can access it as you would with a normal JavaScript array (in case you are sure its ALWAYS only 1 object, you can select the first index right away):

```
let obj = response[0];
```

When you got the object, just access the value you want as you would with a normal JavaScript object:

```
let val = obj.maturitydays;
```